# event for user subscription in onesignal

Tags: javascript, onesignal

Is there a event like addListenerForNotificationOpened but for when user subscribe to the notification, so when in the callback or promise resolve can send tags for that user that just subscribed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found the answer in the folling link of issues in OneSignal](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/287)

```
OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('subscriptionChange');
      if (isSubscribed) {
        OneSignal.sendTags({
          user_id: noticeChannelPush
        }).then(function () {
          console.log('tag:' + noticeChannelPush);
        });
      }
    });
```

where it detects when the state of subscription is change from subscribe to unsubscribe, tested and works as intended.